# Is there a way to find out, how long the app is installed

Tags: iphone, installation

I would like to implement a pop-up which appears after a certain time the user has used the app. I wonder if I can get the installation date of my app out of the users iPhone? Or is there a better approach to get this done?
Sorry, was not clear about my requirement, it's less about usage per session but how long the user has installed the app. Thats why I thought I might be checking against an available installation date.

Comment: start a timer in applicationDidFinishLaunching ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user opens the application for the first time save that date to `NSUserDefaults`. That will be your installation date, then after you've recorded that date, you can compare to that date every time you open the application. That will tell you how long the app has been installed